# How to use 'flag' variables other than using as global?

Tags: c, embedded, flags, pic

I'm using several no of flags for setting the flags in a mini embedded project.I would like to know what is the best method to use these variables which indicate certain states in the project.I'm using c18 compiler and pic18f controller.

> flag1..flag 2..flag3..denote  state1, state2,state3..and corresponding
>   actions were performed.

Making global is an option.

But what is most preferred method through which i can handle the 'flags' well in the embedded system?

Comment: If used inside ISR.I should  specify that it is a type qualifier.Sorry

Comment: You should certainly read Jack Ganssle's [A Pox on Globals](http://www.embedded.com/electronics-blogs/break-points/4025723/A-pox-on-globals)

Answer (score 3):

First of all, whenever you have lots of "flags", tread carefully. In embedded systems, it is easy to get "flag spaghetti", which consists of a lot of complex dependencies. So examine what flags you have: are they related, can they co-exist etc. If so, it is usually better to merge them into an enum. If the flags specify states, then for better program stability, consider writing your whole program as a state machine. And set the flags in a consistent manner, at specific places in the program. Rather than doing so all over the place.

As for how to store them: there is never a reason in a C program to use a global variable, where the definition of a global variable is a variable declared at file scope, which is visible to the whole program.

If you are using a single-threaded/single-process program, then declaring a variable at file scope is fine. But you must declare it as `static`, so that it is a *private file scope variable* rather than a global one.

`volatile` has nothing to do with scope or program design. To prevent incorrect compiler optimizations, you should always declare a variable `volatile` if it is shared between the main program and the ISR.

(Please note that `volatile` does not guarantee any atomic access, it does not protect against race conditions between the ISR and the main program.)

Comment: Thank you very much @Lundin . But if i have a flag_1 in main and i'm using that in file1 and file1 need to know the state of 'flag_1'.Making global is all i'm aware of and i'm also aware it is evil.Then how could i tweak the problem?.Pardon me I'm just a beginner eager to learn.

Comment: @Rookie91 You should design everything in an object-orientated manner. How to do in your specific case is impossible to tell without details. You have to place everything where it belongs. Where "flag_1" belongs, nobody knows (including yourself, 6 months later), because the variable name is so poor. If "flag_1" is some hardware status flag, then it should be renamed to something suitable and placed together with the hardware driver. If it is related to the state machine, it should be renamed to something else and placed with the state machine (which might be implemented in main).